# Linking error with nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, linker, singleton, nested

I have a system of classes that inherit from a template that itself inherit from a Singleton.

The problem is that the static member *ms_Singleton* can't be linked correctly in the Specialized version of my class.
And I received the following error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class MyBase * Singleton >::ms_Singleton"

My code is:

```
template <typename T> 
class Singleton
{
protected:
    static T* ms_Singleton;

public:
    Singleton( void )
    {
        ms_Singleton = static_cast< T* >( this );
    }
    static void init(void){};
    static T& getSingleton( void )
    {   assert( ms_Singleton );  return ( *ms_Singleton ); }
};



template <class T>
class MyBase : public Singleton< MyBase<T> >
{
    public:
        MyBase()
        {
        }
};


/*template <class T>
MyBase<T>* Singleton< MyBase<T> >::ms_Singleton = 0;*/

class MySpecialized : public MyBase<MySpecialized >
{
    public:
        MySpecialized()
        {
        }
};

template <>
MySpecialized* Singleton<MySpecialized>::ms_Singleton = 0; 

int main()
{
    MySpecialized t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
template <class T>
Base<T>* Singleton< Base<T> >::ms_Singleton = 0;
```

to

```
template <class T>
T* Singleton<T>::ms_Singleton = 0;
```

Check http://ideone.com/7B0Da

Comment: Thanx Pawel!! It works like a charm in my sample project! I will try to implement it now in my big project. :)

Comment: @zmatz Good to hear that. Please accept the answer - there should be some kind of green ok sign below points on the left.